# Is there a way to compare two sets and determine which ones is the closer match?

Tags: statistics

I have the following set of data:

| IDX | Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.36 | 12.24 | 12.91 |
| 2 | 17.78 | 17.61 | 18.09 |
| 3 | 20.11 | 19.89 | 20.13 |
| 4 | 20.93 | 20.69 | 20.81 |
| 5 | 21.49 | 21.28 | 21.31 |
| 6 | 21.43 | 21.28 | 21.26 |
| 7 | 21.35 | 21.24 | 21.19 |
| 8 | 21.40 | 21.29 | 21.27 |
| 9 | 20.76 | 20.66 | 20.71 |
| 10 | 20.64 | 20.56 | 20.70 |
| 11 | 20.11 | 20.22 | 20.18 |
| 12 | 16.26 | 16.42 | 16.31 |
| 13 | 8.73 | 8.67 | 8.44 |

All the 3 sets are similar to each other. Looking at numbers, I would say the **Set 2** is closest to the **Set 1**.

I tried calculating the sum of the variances of **Set 1** to **Set 2** differences and the sum of the variances of **Set 1** and **Set 3** differences, and it does indicate that the **Set 3** is less like the **Set 2**.

What other methods are there to test for which set is more like the first set?  Would there be a better method than the one I used?

Comment: "closest" isn't well defined.  What metric are you using?   One common suggestion would be the sum of squared differences, $d(\{x_i\}, \{y_i\})=\sum (x_i-y_i)^2$, but other metrics are possible.  Once you have settled on a metric, the computations ought to be easy.

Comment: Indeed, there are many choice of distance metric which will all accomplish different things. Suppose you had two sets of 10 items where all items are identical, except for the last one which misses by 10 units, and another two sets of 10 items where all items differ by 1 unit. Depending on your choice of distance metric, you may determine that *either* pair of sets are the closer match.

Comment: @lulu, I guess that is my quest, what metric choices are there?  I just do not know where I can get that list.

Comment: There is no universal answer to that. It  depends on what you intend to do with the connotation.  I have you a standard example, if you have no prior notion, why not use that?

Comment: @lulu, I can use that one, I just wanted to explore other options.

Comment: In practice, data does not arise in a vacuum.  There are preconceptions regarding the nature of the data and possible connections with other data.  We can then try to model those preconceptions and let the numbers sharpen our models (or reject the models, as often happens).  Metrics are chosen with full understanding of the models.

Comment: For cheap examples, suppose $x=\{x_i\}$ is some time series.  Which do you think is "closer" to $x$:  $\{x_i+1\}$, $\{2x_i\}$, $\{x_i+\epsilon\}$, $\{x_i \times \epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon$ represents noise (say a Gaussian with some mean and variance, small if you want.  To be clear:  there isn't a correct answer here, just trying to illustrate what different notions of "closeness" might look like.